# Single directional electric field insulator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, insulators

Is there any material, (kind of like a one way mirror), which allows an Electric Field to pass through from one direction, but not from the other?

Thanks.

Edit:
As Ali has pointed out, one way mirrors do not actually block light from filtering through.

Maybe I could reformulate it by asking. Is there anyway to polarize Electric Fields in the way we do for light, ie the Force vector applied to a particle behind said insulator would only act in one direction?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you, but unfortunately there is nothing as a one-way mirror! Look at [this xkcd](http://what-if.xkcd.com/14/) and this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_mirror)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was unaware of how it worked. I have reformulated my question to a new one.

Comment: *polarize* Electric field? I don't think the electric field is a wave to have planes of polarization.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the interesting question . If I had a box with a special door that would allow high energy photons in and low energy photons out it would be in violation of the conservation of energy .The reason being is the box would become hot allowing for free energy . The door is called Maxwell's demon . However in mechanical devices and electronics we seem to have these demons , a check value , one way value , and in electronics a diode that allows electrons to move in one direction only.

If I place a check value on our box to let air in only the air pressure will increase with changes in outside air pressure and sound energy. Is this free energy ? If I place a electric diode on a condenser then attach it to a antenna random electromagnetic noise will charge the condense to a few volts . Is this free energy ? In both cases no as the energy was already there.

However as far as entropy is concerned there could be a problem as energy is now concentrated in the box. Entropy in the sense that warm water is now becoming hot water in the box while the outside cools a small amount . It is now a balancing act of outside average temperature being lower justifying the energy requirement to force entropy in the wrong direction.

On balance my vote is check values and diodes do not violate the conservation of energy. As to the question at hand there is the Faraday effect of a magnetic field to twist the polarization of photons. The twist is proportional to the length and strength of the magnetic field as well as the material the photons are moving through. By setting the magnetic field to twist the polarization of the photons 45 degrees . As the Faraday twist effect is not directional . By this I mean a photon that is coming in will be twisted in the same direction . This means a photon leaving can never return if it is followed by another photo that is leaving as the reflected photon will be twisted 45 degrees on the way out then another 45 degrees on the way in providing a means to isolate incoming from outgoing photons . It is not exactly a one way mirror but it seems to get the job done . The google buzz words for this device is optical isolator or optical diode .